# VBA create a Pivot table using the current selection, not specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a Pivot table using the range I have selected. I have a code that I created using the record function but it always gives the pivot table a specific range instead of using the selection like I wanted (so that the code would work with different data sets). Here's the code I have that I'd like to change

```
'Select the data for the Pivot table
Range("N1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select

'Create the Pivot table to the sheet named "Pivot"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Updated data!R1C1:R95C27", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Pivot!R2C2", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7
Sheets("Pivot").Select
```

I would like to change the SourceData:="Updated data!R1C1:R95C27" to be SourceData = CurrentSelection. How is this done?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Probably something like `Sleection.Address` as R1C1 style may be useful here. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address

Comment: Maybe try like this : `Set rg = Application.InputBox("select the range", Type:=8)` ---> this will ask the user to select the range in a table (must include the header). Then `src = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & rg.Address` ---> this is going to the string for the pivot table SourceData. Then : `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src, Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R2C2", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7`

Comment: Just remember that you can't run the sub for the second time. Except you delete first the whole cells in your sheet Pivot. Then you put the create code for the Pivot Table. If there is already the pivot table in Sheet Pivot resulted from the sub in the first run, if you don't delete the whole cells of sheet Pivot first, then it will throw you an error, because the macro create the pt, by default the name of the pt is "PivotTable1". Since there is already "PivotTable1" in sheet Pivot, it throw you an error. Another way, have the pt already exist. Then make a sub to change the data source.

Comment: @karma Hi, I tried your code but I get an "Reference isn't valid" error. Here's my code:

Comment: Set rg = Application.InputBox("select the range", Type:=8)
    '---> this will ask the user to select the range in a table (must include the header).
    src = ActiveSheet.Name & "Pivot" & rg.Address
    '---> this is going to the string for the pivot table SourceData.
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src, Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R2C2", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7
    'Create the Pivot table to the sheet named "Pivot"
    Sheets("Pivot").Select

Comment: Do I have something wrong, or is it just because that the sourcedata doesn't work?

Comment: At what line it throw you the error ? Step run the sub, so you know the line where it throw you the error. Another thing, when you run the test sub, is there a pivot table in cell B2 of your Pivot sheet ?

Comment: @karma it throws the error in the line with ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src, Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R2C2", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7 ' (because of the SourceData isn't valid). And there's no Pivot table. I think the thing I'm trying to accomplish can't be done

Comment: @user15012453, sorry my mistake... please have the src like this : `src = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`. In my side, using `DefaultVersion:=7` throw me an error, so I record the macro and this kind of line work : `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= src, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PIVOT!R2C2",TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14`

Comment: @karma Hey, this finally works! Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: @user15012453, you're welcome and glad that it finally work with you.